# Quartz 2.2.2 : org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle, quartz-scheduler, oracle-adf, quartz

I'm using Quartz Scheduler 2.2.2.

I have created a schema called 'SCHEDULER_DEV' in Oracle Database.

> CREATE USER SCHEDULER_DEV IDENTIFIED BY SCHEDULER_DEV DEFAULT
>   TABLESPACE USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS

I have provided below grants for this schema - create/alter session, create table, view, sequence, synonym, type and procedure.

In the qrtz_locks table, I have added 2 entries:

> INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS(SCHED_NAME,LOCK_NAME)
>   VALUES('QuartzScheduler', 'STATE_ACCESS');
>
> INSERT INTO QRTZ_LOCKS(SCHED_NAME,LOCK_NAME)
>   VALUES('QuartzScheduler', 'TRIGGER_ACCESS');

I configured my web.xml like below:

*>

> ```
>     <listener-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
> </listener>
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>config-file</param-name>
>     <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
> </context-param>
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
>     <param-value>true</param-value>
> </context-param>
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
>     <param-value>true</param-value>
> </context-param>
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>start-on-load</param-name>
>     <param-value>true</param-value>
> </context-param>
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>start-delay-seconds</param-name>
>     <param-value>10</param-value>
> </context-param>*
> ```

*

My quartz.properties file include as below along with other key-value pairs:

> org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=QuartzScheduler
>   org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=SchedulerDS
>   org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=SCHEDULER_DEV.QRTZ_
>   org.quartz.dataSource.SchedulerDS.jndiURL=jdbc/schedulerds
>   org.quartz.dataSource.SchedulerDS.java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory

When I run my page I get the following error:

> > org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist  [See nested
> >     exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view
> >     does not exist ]  at
> >     org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:157)
> >       at
> >     org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DBSemaphore.obtainLock(DBSemaphore.java:113)
> >       at
> >     org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3270)
> >       at
> >     org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3870)
> >       at
> >     org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3907)

Answer (score 0):

I guest problem is your config here:
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=SCHEDULER_DEV.QRTZ_

Try to change to: org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_ and show me if it work.

P/s: If you using another Oracle schema, check if you have grant permission (select, update, insert, delete) to SCHEDULER_DEV on quartz tables.

Answer (score 0):

I got into this issue as well and I can point you to the class and put a debugger in class StdRowLockSemaphore and

```
     ps = conn.prepareStatement(expandedSQL);
     ps.setString(1, lockName);
```

I think if you inspect the lock name and the SQL you will be able to find out which table it is accessing, in my case, I had these properties (org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ2_)  which was not taking effect because we wanted to identify them with the version that it is 2+